# How can I get to the root folder of another project in a .NET Core solution?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I need to read the settings file (`appsettings.json`) from another project in my solution. When I use:

```cs
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

From within the current project, I get the following path:

> {projectRootFolder}\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\

My question is: How can I get to the exact same folder in *another* project in the *same* solution? Or is there a better way to access the settings file from another project within the current solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly there are two misconceptions:

1. It has little sense to access output directory of an another project as the structure has sense in compile time only. You will not have the same structure in run-time once the application is "published".
2. The `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the current working directory. It is just a coincidence to be set to project output directory by Visual Studio. It can be totally different directory.

It is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. I recommend using the configuration system provided by .net core to access the configuration and add that other appsettings.json as another [configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#json-configuration-provider).

If you really need to open the settings file then the project with the settings file (A) should mark the file as "Copy to Output Directory" and the project to open the file (B) should reference the project A. So the settings file will be copied to output of the project A too.

Comment: I'm trying to read configuration from another project, specifically the connection string which I don't want to have to duplicate into the current project. To do this I have to map the appsettings.json from the other project into my current project. Both are in the same solution. Is there a better, more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: The main question here is whether there is any dependency between B (executing project) and A (project containing settings file). If A is a library that B is referencing then I would move the setting to the B project (settings should be in executable project). If A is another but independent executable and you just don't want to duplicate the value, then extract the shared settings to a separate file and add that file as linked into the B project, mark as "copy to output" and add it as another file configuration provider.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is not possible. There's no inherent way for ASP.NET Core to know where a totally different app running in a totally different process is located.

If you need to access appsettings.json from another project, then you would need to include it as a linked file in your project, and set it to copy to output. Then, you're accessing it actually from your project (which is all you *can* do), but the file itself is shared.

However, this is almost always a bad idea, and usually a sign that you're doing something wrong. If you truly do need to share the settings, then what you *should* be doing is putting them in a distributed config provider like Azure Key Vault or similar, where both projects can independently access the settings from a common store.